# ASP.NET Core MVC Entity Framework binding for sub entities

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Let's suppose I have these 2 entities:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long id_person {get;set;}

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(255)")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public String name {get;set;}
}

public class InterestCenter
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long id_interest {get;set;}

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(255)")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public String name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to set a many to many relationship between this 2 entities. This mean a `Person` can have many interest centers.

Here is what I've done:

```
public class PersonHasInterestCenter
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long id {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("person")]
    public long id_person {get;set;}
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("interestcenter")]
    public long id_interest {get;set;}
    public virtual InterestCenter interestcenter { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a controller action and cshtml razor view in order to edit and save a `Person`. What I want to do is to display a set of checkboxes with all available interst centers.

Here is what I've done:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(long id, [Bind("id_person,name")] Person p)
{
    ViewBag.interestcenters = mydbcontext.interestcenters;
    ViewBag.message = "";

    if (p.name == "")
    {
        ViewBag.message = "You need to set name.";
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        ViewBag.message = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
    }
    else
    {
        mydb_context.Update(p);
        await mydb_context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(p);
}
```

And here is the associated cshtml razor view:

```
@model myproject.Person

<form asp-action="MyAction">
    <div>@ViewBag.message</div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="id_person" />
    <input asp-for="name" />

@foreach (var name in ViewBag.interestcenters)
{
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_THERE" />@item.name
}

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Everything works great for create or update person's name but I have a problem with interest center checkboxes. I have also tried to create a view model. But I do not manage to make it work...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is ... use viewmodels whenever have the chance.

In order to bind those interests you could create something similar to:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public List<InterestCenterViewModel> InterestCenters { get; set; }
} 

public class InterestCenterViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On the get method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(long id)
{
    var _InterestCenters = mydbcontext.interestcenters;

    // Create your vm here
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        UserId = id,
        InterestCenters = _InterestCenters.Select(p => new InterestCenterViewModel
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name
            IsSelected = false
        }).ToList()
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

On your post:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // Something was not filled or did not match your requirements
    if (!ViewState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // All good. To your stff here

    return Ok();
}
```

So all you need is to pass the list of interests created using the above model to the view:

```
<input asp-for="UserId" type="hidden" />
@for(int i = 0; i < MyViewModel.InterestCenters.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="MyViewModel.InterestCenters[i].IsSelected" />@MyViewModel.InterestCenters[i].Name
}
```

When working with lists you need to use `for` instead of `foreach`. The html generated is using that index `i` instead of the name which is the way to make the difference between items.

Here is a link describing how viewmodels and asp.net works: [Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

Comment: Thanks but how do you embed this viewmodel in the controller ?

Comment: I edited my response to help you get started with vm. I posted a link to the documentation which i recommend taking a look at.

Comment: When i postback, i do not see interestcenter's name but i can see checkboxes. If someone adds an interest center in database, it does something wrong because checkbox inputs are identified by there postion (i) and not there id...

Comment: For the names you just need to include the `<input type="hidden" asp-for="MyViewModel.InterestCenters[i].Name" />` in the loop.